# Ring homomorphism $f$ from field to non-trivial ring where $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is not the zero ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When I looked at the wikipedia page about ring homomorphisms ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism#Properties)) I noticed the following statement:

> Let $f:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism.
>
> If $R$ is a field, $S$ is not the zero ring, and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is not the zero
>   ring then $f$ is injective.

My question is why the fact that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is not the zero ring is required as I don't see where this would be used in a proof.

Comment: Maybe $f(x)=0$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: but isn't f(1) = 1 required for f to be a ring morphism?

Comment: Well then indeed $im(f)$ is automatically not the zero ring if both $R$ and $S$ are not the zero ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an error in the Wikipedia page; the assumption that the image is not the zero ring is unnecessary.  If ring homomorphisms are not defined to be unital (that is, $f(1)=1$), then it is necessary, since otherwise $f$ could just map everything to $0$.  However, the Wikipedia page does define ring homomorphisms to be unital, so this is not an issue.

Comment: The zero homomorphism to the trivial ring $\{0\}$ *is* unital.  I think that's what the authors had in mind.

Comment: But the statement also includes the requirement that $S$ is not the zero ring.

Comment: Oh *that* part is superfluous. Got crossed up.